# Git Bash Copy Paste auto-enter

Tags: git, git-bash

So I know how to copy and paste using Git Bash's shortcut commands, but I can't figure out how to disable the auto-enter feature when I'm trying to copy paste more than one thing. I am just now learning how to use Git and I want to use the following:

```
git log
```

and then

```
git diff {copy paste from git log commit 1} {commit 2}
```

but it auto-enters as soon as I paste the first commit (which is like 80 characters long, so typing out is too painful). Using the `git --version` command, I get: `2.17.0.windows.1`.

EDIT: Since a comment mentioned not highlighting the newline character, I watched as the terminal auto-highlighted all the way to right as I highlighted from right-to-left. Apparently, one must highlight from left-to-right. It fixed the problem, so thank you!

Comment: When you copy anything, be sure you don't include the EOL character in your selection.

Comment: Since you found a solution to your problem, you should post it as an answer below rather than simply editing your question. It will also help if you clarify by what you mean by the terminal auto-highlighting. Do you mean that you are not using the mouse to highlight text from the `git log` command? What are you doing instead?

Comment: Highlighting right to left to avoid the EOL should probably be in a separate answer. Note that the questioner can also create answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a comment mentioned not highlighting the newline character, I watched as the terminal auto-highlighted all the way to right as I highlighted from right-to-left. Apparently, one must highlight from left-to-right. It fixed the problem, so thank you!

By auto-highlight I meant that I started highlighting, using my mouse, from the end of the text (right-most text) going to the left. As soon as I started dragging, the highlighted area extended itself automatically to the end of the entire console line (all the way to the right of the console window). This must have picked up the newline character, so when I pasted, it also ran the command.

Answer (score 3):

When you highlight something to copy, be sure you don't select the EOL character. This means you should not triple click. One solution is to select everything but the last character on the line that you want to copy. Then you will have to manually type the final character.

Note that if you are copying a SHA-1 hash for a commit, you can use enough of the leading digits to uniquely identify the commit. You do not need the full hash. Typically 5 or 6 leading digits is enough.